# Objective-c [GPPSignIn sharedInstance].homeServerAuthorizationCode is nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I'm stuck since a few days ago on a...strange problem, when I authenticate in the Google API in my iOS app, using the GPPSignIn shared instance, the homeServerAuthorizationCode is nil, and there is no error :o I have to signout the user and the re-authenticate to get this code to send to my server :/

It works, but it's pretty dirty, and it doesn't provide a good user experience :(

Here is the code I use :

```
- (IBAction)googleConnect:(id)sender {
    [[GPPSignIn sharedInstance] authenticate];
}

- (void)finishedWithAuth:(GTMOAuth2Authentication *)auth
                   error:(NSError *)error {
    if (!error) {
        NSString *code = [GPPSignIn sharedInstance].homeServerAuthorizationCode;

        NSLog(@"google code : %@", code);
        if (code) {
            // do my stuff with the code
        } else {
            [[GPPSignIn sharedInstance] signOut];
            [[GPPSignIn sharedInstance] authenticate];
        }
    } else {
        NSLog(@"%@", error);
    }
}
```

And here is the configuration of the GPPSignIn singleton. I do it in the appDelegate :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    GPPSignIn *signIn = [GPPSignIn sharedInstance];
    signIn.shouldFetchGooglePlusUser = YES;

    signIn.clientID = googleClientID;
    signIn.homeServerClientID = googleHomeClientID;

    signIn.scopes = @[ kGTLAuthScopePlusLogin ];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: ``homeServerAuthorizationCode`` was ``nil`` for me too.  Thank god you posted this question---I can at least sign out before authenticating ...